# sending Imagestream frame to Opencv fails

Tags: flutter, opencv, dart, ffi

The problem is while using the camera and passing frames by ImageStream,
I keep getting `src->data == nullptr` from the c++ code (OpenCV) while invoking the `imdecode` function. How come?

I have debugged the issue and I have found out in the getByte function,
I get:

- img.height = 480
- img.width = 720

In my opinion each plane should be of length 345600 (480*720)
but I got:

- img.planes[0].bytes.length = 368592
- img.planes[1].bytes.length = 184271
- img.planes[2].bytes.length = 184271

How can it be the image's planes don't have the same length??

The following block is from the flutter app:

```
  initCamera() {
cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
cameraController.initialize().then((value) {
  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {
    cameraController.startImageStream((imageStream) {
      cameraImage = imageStream;
      print("Frame number: $frameCounter");
      frameCounter++;
      res = imageMetaData.applyConvertToMatrix(cameraImage);

      // runModel();
    });
  });
});
```

}

Calling the c++ code by ffi:

```
 Uint8List getBytes(CameraImage img) {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    //Write all the values from a Uint8List into the buffer.
    img.planes.forEach((plane) => allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes));
    return allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Pointer<Uint8> intListToArray(Uint8List list) {

    final Pointer<Uint8> ptr = calloc.allocate<Uint8>(list.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      ptr.elementAt(i).value = list[i];
    }
    return ptr;
  }

  Future<bool> applyConvertToMatrix(CameraImage img) async {
     func_convert_to_matrix = nativeAddLib.lookup<NativeFunction<Pointer<Void> Function(
                Pointer<Uint8>, Pointer<Int32>)>>("convert_from_img_array_to_matrix")
    .asFunction();

     Uint8List bytes = getBytes(img);

     Pointer<void> ptr;
     Pointer<Uint8> imgBytes;

     imgByteLength.value = bytes.length;

     imgBytes = intListToArray(bytes);

     ptr = func_convert_to_matrix(imgBytes, imgByteLength); //invoking the c++ code

     return true;
   }
```

The C++ code:

```
void *convert_from_img_array_to_matrix(
    unsigned char *img,
    int32_t *imgLengthBytes) {


cv::Mat *src = new Mat();
int32_t len_bytes = *imgLengthBytes;
std::vector<unsigned char> m;

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "NATIVE", "Len bytes: %d", len_bytes);

while ( len_bytes>=0 )
{
    m.push_back(*(img++));
    len_bytes--;
}

*src = cv::imdecode(m, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
if (src->data == nullptr)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "NATIVE", "You reached nullptr");
    return nullptr;
}

if (DEBUG_NATIVE)
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "NATIVE", "convert_from_img_array_to_matrix() ---  len before:%d  len after:%d  width:%d  height:%d",
        *imgLengthBytes, src->step[0] * src->rows,
        src->cols, src->rows);

*imgLengthBytes = src->step[0] * src->rows;    
return src;
}
```

Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if image planes have different sizes, you are dealing with chroma-subsampled data, likely some type of YUV. I would highly recommend getting rid of regular pointers and either working with "RAII" or smart pointers (c++ has `shared_ptr`). in any case, cv::Mat are containers that can share data already.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you!!
yes yesterday I printed the img.format.group and found out it is of type: yuv420. What do you mean "in any case, cv::Mat are containers that can share data already" can you please elaborate by giving a simple example? Thank you

Comment: `cv::Mat *src = new Mat();` **never ever** do that. why? because a dozen lines later you overwrite that pointer, and that object living in the heap just became a **leak** because you didn't `delete` it. just say `cv::Mat src;` (yes that's it) and `src = cv::imdecode(m, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);` and test using `src.empty()` (not any nullptr stuff) oh and **do not** return `void*`. return `cv::Mat`... I see you have to use some foreign function interface. I hope it can do normal C++ types/classes/objects, not just numbers and pointers. it would be awful if it couldn't.